# how to mark cell when the row data is changing on ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report.
I have an order columns.
I want to mark both rows where order is changing in yellow

[image: Screenshot of Report Data and preview]

How to do like this?

Comment: I used this expression:

     =iif(RunningValue(Fields!STR_ORDER_ID.Value,CountDistinct,Nothing) Mod 2, "LIGHTBLUE", "SILVER")

but this expression just show groups colour:(

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Make a Parent Group on your `STR_ORDER_ID`. Don't create a header and remove the column only (after you create the group). The only issue here is that you'll get the coloring on the first and last row of the report.

```
    =IIF(RowNumber("GroupName") =  CountRows("GroupName"), "LightBlue",
 IIF(RowNumber("GroupName") = 1, "LightBlue","Silver"))
```